# Oscillations in motor control systems

Tags: control-engineering, motors, control-theory

I have an underdamped control system for a DC motor. It is only a mathematical model so I can't visualise the motor.

I can change the value of the "k" or compensator. I have noticed that changing this value changes the frequency of oscillation in the step response.

I was wondering what the effect of increased oscillation in a control system would be on a DC motor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An under-damped control system with a DC motor, particularly if there is backlash in the system, can cause the direction of the motor to switch very rapidly, causing large inductive loads, and potential damage to your circuitry.