# oscillation motion from DC motor (computer fan)

Tags: electrical-engineering, motors, prototyping

I intend to make an oscillating motion from a simple computer DC fan (say 5V).

My question is: could a signal generator with a sinusoidal signal of (say voltage 5V  and frequency of 5 Hz) be used to power such a DC fan to produce the oscillating motion ?

Second question:
it is related to [Oscillations in motor control systems](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18427/oscillations-in-motor-control-systems).
Will there be a damage for a low frequency and low voltage input to the fan ?

For additional info, the load is lightweight, and the mechanical rotation is about ±45 degrees.

Comment: How large of an angle do you want the motor to move through, and how big of a load are you putting on it (i.e., *what* are you putting on it)?

Comment: It is lightweight load (e.g. as in a piece of small cardboard), and the angle can be at least 45 degree.

Comment: Sorry -- could you edit your question with that comment, to complete the question?  It's a StackExchange thing.  When you do, say whether you mean $\pm$45 degrees, or $\pm$22.5 degrees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

computer fans are driven with direct current but contain a circuit which chops the DC into pulses that sequentially excite sets of electromagnet coils inside the motor to make it turn. these motors are called *brushless dc* motors and cannot be operated the way you want to.

You can instead make a "conventinal" or *brushed DC* motor vibrate the way you want simply by feeding it AC instead of DC.

A better way to make vibrations out of electric signals is to feed them into the terminals of a *loudspeaker*.

Comment: could you elaborate more on second part: "feeding it AC instead of DC". Say the signal generator is amplified..

Comment: yes, run the signal generator through a small audio power amp (as used for car stereos) and then connect that to the motor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no, maybe.

Computer fans are specialized, cheap brushless motors, with their own built-in controllers.  The ones that I took apart 30 years ago had 4-pole coil assemblies and an unknown number of poles in the magnets, and a 3-transistor circuit that actually made the rotation happen.

You should be able to convert one to a galvonometer by disassembling it and driving the coils directly, in two pairs, in opposition.  Whether this will give you enough rotation is an unknown to me -- it depends on whether the magnet has two poles or six (either of which should work, for a fan).

As long as you don't drive the thing with too much current you shouldn't damage anything -- the two things to worry about are overheating the coils and demagnetizing the magnets.

Comment: Plus for " overheating the coils and demagnetizing the magnets.".